# How to convert time.strptime into an integer for datatime.date() Python 2

Tags: python-2.7, python-datetime

How would I convert the result from strptime into an integer value or a value that can be used by date.date()?

```
convertTOdate = time.strptime('2007-07-18 10:03:19', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

duedate = datetime.datetime(convertTOdate)
```

A Solution on stackoverflow was to do:

Use time.mktime() to convert the time tuple (in localtime) into seconds since the Epoch, then use datetime.fromtimestamp() to get the datetime object.

```
 from time import mktime
 from datetime import datetime

 dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(mktime(struct))
```

I do not want to get the local time as it would not work with my function

I am using Python 2

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following approach.

```
from datetime import datetime

def time_in_seconds(dt):
    epoch = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0)
    delta = dt - epoch
    return delta.total_seconds()

convertTOdate = datetime.strptime('2007-07-18 10:03:19', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
duedate = time_in_seconds(convertTOdate)
```

returns `1184752999.0` which is equivalent to **2007-07-18 10:03:19**

```
duedate = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(duedate)
print duedate
```

Just remember before using the following two:

`fromtimestamp` give you the date and time in local time and `utcfromtimestamp` gives you the date and time in UTC.

Comment: Hi , thank you. I am trying to get the time for date.date() to convert to UCT without having any references to the local time. I am using my own epoch. I will have to manually strip the values into a dict and then place that in the datetime function. I will post it to thsi question when I am done. thank you again @WasiAhmad